# Hibernate objects and Java reflection

Tags: java, hibernate

I am lazily loading an object from hibernate using the following line of code
`Object object = session.load(Class.forName(javaType), objectId);`

If I print `object.getClass().getSimpleName()` it displays the name of the hibernate proxy and not my implementation class as expected.

However If I then use reflection on this proxy object to return an attribute called children as follows: 
`List children = (List) object.getClass().getMethod("getChildren", new Class[ {}).invoke(object, new Object[]{});`

It is returning a list of objects where `object.getClass().getSimpleName()` on any of the objects returns the implementation class name. Why are these objects not returning the proxy object name?

Answer (score 0):

The list itself can be lazy-loaded, but if you enumerate the elements, an sql query is required and there would be no performance gain to create a proxy for each element (on the contrary).